# Textarea does not wrap text on WebView in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, textarea

The issue is the same as this one: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55166

For reference: a textarea with a long placeholder doesn't get text-wrapped and overflows the control thus showing only partial text. This problem happens both on `WebView` and on the default browser on pre-KitKat devices, but not on pre-ICS devices, so this is a bug that must've been included on 4.0.1.

Has anyone found a workaround for this? Maybe a js library that replaces the textarea with another control?